# Remove minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds from OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

Is there a concise way to strip out all the minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds in `OffsetDateTime`? Here is what I have to do to get what I want.

```
final OffsetDateTime strippedTime = OffsetDateTime.now().withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
System.out.println(strippedTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn")));
```

The code above gives me:

```
2016-11-08 09:00:00.000000000
```

`LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` sadly strips the hours away from the object, so it is no use to me. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What about changing the format to "yyyy-MM-dd HH"?

Comment: I've never used OffsetDateTime myself, but the way you're currently doing it seems already concise...

Comment: @AJPerez I tried to avoid having to remember to explicitly remove all minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds from the object. But you're right. Conciseness is very subjective in this case.

Comment: @BrunoDM The OffsetDateTime object will be converted to nanoseconds in a computation. It is not intended to be used for displaying value. I put the displaying code there just to illustrate what value I am seeking.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [`OffsetDateTime.truncatedTo(TemporalUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) with [`ChronoUnit.HOURS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#HOURS):

```
 OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)`